# Azure AD B2C - Enable MS 365 Sign Up / Login

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have configured identity provider as described in this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-microsoft-account?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_AAD_B2CAdmin)

[image]

Sign up page shows up as in the photo. When entering existing office 365 email address, it doesn't accept. It only accepts personal Microsoft accounts.

Found an old feature request what was declined.
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/16849006-aadb2c-integrate-office-365-to-work-with-b2c

Is it still the same OR is there any alternate way ?

**Update (couldnt page photo in comment, updating the question)**

[image]

I chose 2nd option for multi-tenancy from suggestion and now it gives me error
*The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want any O365 Account to sign in to your AAD B2C protected app, you need to federate with AAD Multi Tenant using Custom Policies.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant-custom?tabs=app-reg-ga

Comment: any plans to integrate AAD Multi tenancy into user flows?

Answer (score 0):

[Set up sign-up and sign-in with a Microsoft account using Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-microsoft-account?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_AAD_B2CAdmin) is only for personal Microsoft accounts.

You should configure Azure AD IDP by following [Set up sign-in for a specific Azure Active Directory organization in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant).

Then you can use existing office 365 account to sign in.

Comment: Thanks @Allen. I gave it a go with 2nd option for multi-tenancy from suggestion and also added custom OIDC provider. It gives me error - The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account. any suggestions ? I need user to be able to sign up using office 365 accounts irrespective of org. I updated the question with new info.

Comment: @Krunal It means that the O365 account your using to signing in is not from the Azure AD tenant which you configured as the idp of B2C. For example, you need to register the Azure AD app in the tenant `contoso.com`. When you configure it into B2C, you also need to specify **Metadata url** as `https://login.microsoftonline.com/contoso.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`. After that, you should use an account from this tenant(eg. `test@contoso.com`) to sign in.

Comment: @Krunal And if you just want to **sign up** using office 365 accounts irrespective of org, you don't need to configure Azure AD IDP. Make sure that **Local accounts** is enabled for the signupsignin user flow. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/0k8Ho.png. It's unnecessary to select the Azure AD idp you configured, Just use the default signup link to sign up the existing O365 account. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZbqU.png.

Comment: @Krunal Note that configuring external AAD idp just allows you to **sign in** ( without sign up) directly with the AAD (O365) account in that tenant. For **sign up**, you just need to sign up with the default local account option.

Comment: what you suggested already works, however I dont think single sign on would be possible between ms 365 and my application ??